# How to export data on excel using linq?

Tags: sql, excel, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem, my data does populate but the challenge is now, data is not corresponding to my record list. E.g if i do a query for Year, Week 2020, 53 both front end this has no record and so does on my query on the database. On my MVC application i get duplicate record for year, week and day. Let me share my logic with you all. My linq sql does not check if there are no record either and im stuck, please help mates.

SQL tables for both tables here

```
    SELECT TOP (1000) [WeekId]
          ,[WeekNum]
          ,[Year]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedBy]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
          ,[ModifiedBy]
          ,[InActive]
      FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[Week]
    
    SELECT TOP (1000) [ProductionDayId]
          ,[WeekId]
          ,[ProductionDate]
          ,[DayOfWeek]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedBy]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
          ,[ModifiedBy]
          ,[InActive]
      FROM [ProductionManagement].[Schedule].[ProductionDay]
      Order by ProductionDate
```

This is my model class

```
        public class ExtractionViewModel
        {
            public string Year { get; set; }
    
            public int Week { get; set; }
    
            
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    
           // public string VW240 { get; set; }
    
            public string VW250 { get; set; }
    
            public string VW270 { get; set; }
    
            public string VW2502PA { get; set; }
    
            public string VW270PA { get; set; }
        }
```

And this is the method that loads it

```
          public IList<ExtractionViewModel> GetExtractionViewModels()
            {
                  int Count;
                
                var db = new ProductionManagementEntities();
    
                var scheduleList = (from p in db.ProductionDays
                                    
                                    from m in db.Models
                                    from mx in db.Models
                                    from mt in db.Models
                                    from mv in db.Models
                                    from wk in db.Models
                                   
                                    join w in db.Weeks on p.WeekId equals w.WeekId 
                                    orderby w.Year descending , m.Name descending, p.ProductionDate descending, w.WeekNum descending, mt.Name descending, mx.Name descending, mv.Name descending
```

My problem is on this method exactly there is so much duplicate when i download my excel and compare with query on the database they not complementing and need some here to these records.

```
                                    where (mx.InActive == true)
                                    where (mt.InActive == false)
                                    where(m.InActive == false)
                                    where(mv.InActive == false)
                                    
                                    where (mt.Name == "VW270")
                                    where(mx.Name == "VW250")
                                    where(m.Name == "VW270PA")
                                    where(mv.Name == "VW250/2PA")
    
    
                                    select new ExtractionViewModel
                                    {
    
                                        Year = w.Year,
                                        Day = p.ProductionDate,
                                        Week = w.WeekNum,
                                        VW270 = mt.Name,
                                        VW270PA = m.Name,
                                        VW250 = mx.Name,
                                        VW2502PA = mv.Name, 
                                       
                                        
                                       
    
    
    
    
                                    }).ToList();
    
    
                return scheduleList;
            }
```

The code that generates the Excel file is

```
          public void ExportToExcel()
            {
    
                var v = new GridView();
                v.DataSource = this.GetExtractionViewModels();
                v.DataBind();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExtractionRecords.xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                Response.Charset = "";
                StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
                v.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
                Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
                //return View("DataResult");
            }

  public ActionResult DataResult()
        {
            return View(this.GetExtractionViewModels());
        }
```

// Front end images
[image]

Comment: You don't export any Excel file, you create n HTML table with a fake extension. Don't do that.  Not only is the file a lot larger than it has to, there's no guarantee Excel can read it. It will attempt to import the table contents but any unexpected content can cause trouble. Create a proper file using eg EPPlus or ClosedXML. It's as easy as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(someData);`

Comment: Why so many `where` clauses? If you want to combine conditions use `&&`. And why is the same `Model` set used so many times in the query, without even a JOIN clause? That's what generates multiple copies. Without anything to restrict the results, all individual combinations will be returned

Comment: Your question is a bit "all over the place". Can you make it a more methodical statement of the problem? Show some example data

Comment: If each self-join returns 2 rows, the result will contain 2^5=32 combinations

Comment: @Panagiotis yes i am using closedXML

Comment: @GcobaniMkontwana no you aren't. You're creating an HTML table with GridView and return it with a fake extension and content type

Comment: @Panagiotis ok what could be the workaround this? you mention 2 things are off important that this logic is doing. First one too many where and same model including HTML table with GridView

Comment: @kanavos i am trying to access each field on my Model to interact with my records from the database

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. Does `Model` follow the Entity-Attribute-Value **anti**pattern? That's a very bad idea that makes storing and querying a *lot* harder, slower and riskier. In SQL you'd have to use PIVOT or self-joins to get back a proper row. With ORMs and LINQ things are even harder, as the ORM (and LINQ) expects each property to map to a different column, not a different row. You can't use `PIVOT` in LINQ, so you'd either have to load all matching `Model` rows in memory and group them by ID, or use a SQL query with PIVOT to convert attribute rows into a single row per object

Comment: @Kanavos note taken, how can i improve based on my given scenario? What you mentioned is true, maybe reason why i am stuck to use PIVOT than join to get Model of all records